# Python class using large lookup tables

Tags: python, class, module, constants, lookup-tables

I've been tinkering with Python (v3) on and off for the past few years.  As a learning exercise, I decided a couple weeks ago to refactor a collection of bash scripts I wrote.  I also think some features of the language will dramatically speed up the processing.  These bash scripts typically run for 5 or 6 days processing huge data files.  The Python version also significantly improves the readability and maintainability of the code.

First I got the algorithms working as a program in one file.  The algorithm uses several large lookup tables, implemented variously as lists and dictionaries.  Now I want to break it up - the core logic going into one file, and a second file containing a class(es?) holding the lookup tables and their associated functions.  The data tables take about 350 lines of code, and the functions are about the same size.

*Q: What is the preferred way of structuring the class module file?*

For example, I started doing it this way, let's call it case 1:

```
class Zebra:
    _stripe_keys = [ ....... ]
    _stripe_info = [ [.....], [.....], ... [.....] ]
    _stripes = [ dict(zip( stripe_keys, info )) for info in stripe_info ]
    <<< many such tables >>>
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def function_one(self):
        do something
    def function_two(self):
        do something
    <<< etc... >>>
```

Then I realized this might be better, case 2:

```
_stripe_keys = [ ....... ]
_stripe_info = [ [.....], [.....], ... [.....] ]
_stripes = [ dict(zip( stripe_keys, info )) for info in stripe_info ]
<<< many such tables >>>
class Zebra:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def function_one(self):
        do something
    def function_two(self):
        do something
    <<< etc... >>>
```

And then I saw yet another possibility, case 3, but somehow I'd have to pass the data class into the function class:

```
class ZebraTables:
    _stripe_keys = [ ....... ]
    _stripe_info = [ [.....], [.....], ... [.....] ]
    _stripes = [ dict(zip( stripe_keys, info )) for info in stripe_info ]
    <<< many such tables >>>
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
class Zebra:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def function_one(self):
        do something
    def function_two(self):
        do something
    <<< etc... >>>
```

The data tables are essentially constant.  If there was ever a reason to make two instances of this class, the data should be shared and not duplicated.  The static data in the source code takes tens of MB of memory, combined with additional data read from disk at startup brings the total to about 600MB).  I think this means case 2 is what I want, but I'm not certain.  I come from an embedded background using primarily C, so Object Oriented techniques aren't my specialty - yet!

Comment: If the data is constant, you could just put everything at the module level and be done with it. Only use a class if it makes sense to your code, you don't *have* to use OO for everything.

Comment: Well as soon as you import one of those classes in a script your lookup tables will be loaded into memory. So if you want to avoid that, you'll need to put each of those tables in different modules and import them selectively.

Comment: I agree with @Martijn—besides, modules behave like singleton instances of a class. In fact you can manually add instances of a class to `sys.modules` to make it appear to be an (already imported) module if you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would not store large lists inside the same module with the class. What about saving them in some format in an external python module, that manages them and load them when you need it?

Depending on the size and needs you can use `pickle`, `pandas`, `csv`, or directly an SQL/NoSQL DB.

Comment: That is a good idea.  I've tested it out and I save about 50% initialization time by loading the data from a pickle.  Since these tables are essentially constant, I can compute the data once, pickle it to disk, and just unpickle in normal operation.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions, they helped steer me to a workable solution and a better grasp of module vs class vs instance variables.  I decided to put everything into one class within the module.

```
class Zebra:
    stripe_keys = []
    stripe_info = []
    stripes = defautdict(list)
    <<< many such tables >>>
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.init_stripes()
    def function_one(self):
        do something
    def function_two(self):
        do something
    def init_stripes(self):
        Zebra.stripe_keys.extend([.........])
        Zebra.stripe_info.extend([ [...], [...], ..., [...] ])
        Zebra.stripes.extend([ dict(zip( Zebra.stripe_keys, info )) 
                               for info in Zebra.stripe_info ])
    <<< etc... >>>
```

This arrangement, where I define empty tables at the top and extend/update them with data at the bottom, was necessary to solve a circular reference issues. One of the lists is a jump table referencing functions in the class, so I couldn't define the tables first, nor could I define the functions first.